# FFmpeg: How to add watermark after 60 seconds?

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

Right now I am using:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png \
-filter_complex overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5 \
-codec:a copy -preset ultrafast -async 1 output.mp4
```

I want the watermark to be displayed after 60 seconds in the video.
How can I make so that the video starts, and then after 60 seconds adding in the watermark?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`enable` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) with the [`gte` function](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png \
-filter_complex "overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5:enable='gte(t,60)'" \
-codec:a copy -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```